# Redis crash when turning into replica

Tags: docker, redis

I am using redis through docker in my project with the latest version **5.0.7**.
I keep the default config of redis, except the *appendonly* that i put to **yes** to have persistence of my data.

When i see the *save* config, it is **empty** and it does help me because i don't need rdb backup but the problem is i still have logs **"DB saved on disk"** even if this option is deactivate.

but the real problem is that sometime, the instance redis which is turning in **"standalone"** was trying to turn into replica. I think the reason is because it is doing backups according to my research. This problem is stopping redis to listen to the user requests and my API went down.

Here is my config :

```
  1) "dbfilename"
  2) "dump.rdb"
  3) "requirepass"
  4) ""
  5) "masterauth"
  6) ""
  7) "cluster-announce-ip"
  8) ""
  9) "unixsocket"
 10) ""
 11) "logfile"
 12) ""
 13) "pidfile"
 14) ""
 15) "slave-announce-ip"
 16) ""
 17) "replica-announce-ip"
 18) ""
 19) "maxmemory"
 20) "0"
 21) "proto-max-bulk-len"
 22) "536870912"
 23) "client-query-buffer-limit"
 24) "1073741824"
 25) "maxmemory-samples"
 26) "5"
 27) "lfu-log-factor"
 28) "10"
 29) "lfu-decay-time"
 30) "1"
 31) "timeout"
 32) "0"
 33) "active-defrag-threshold-lower"
 34) "10"
 35) "active-defrag-threshold-upper"
 36) "100"
 37) "active-defrag-ignore-bytes"
 38) "104857600"
 39) "active-defrag-cycle-min"
 40) "5"
 41) "active-defrag-cycle-max"
 42) "75"
 43) "active-defrag-max-scan-fields"
 44) "1000"
 45) "auto-aof-rewrite-percentage"
 46) "100"
 47) "auto-aof-rewrite-min-size"
 48) "67108864"
 49) "hash-max-ziplist-entries"
 50) "512"
 51) "hash-max-ziplist-value"
 52) "64"
 53) "stream-node-max-bytes"
 54) "4096"
 55) "stream-node-max-entries"
 56) "100"
 57) "list-max-ziplist-size"
 58) "-2"
 59) "list-compress-depth"
 60) "0"
 61) "set-max-intset-entries"
 62) "512"
 63) "zset-max-ziplist-entries"
 64) "128"
 65) "zset-max-ziplist-value"
 66) "64"
 67) "hll-sparse-max-bytes"
 68) "3000"
 69) "lua-time-limit"
 70) "5000"
 71) "slowlog-log-slower-than"
 72) "10000"
 73) "latency-monitor-threshold"
 74) "0"
 75) "slowlog-max-len"
 76) "128"
 77) "port"
 78) "6379"
 79) "cluster-announce-port"
 80) "0"
 81) "cluster-announce-bus-port"
 82) "0"
 83) "tcp-backlog"
 84) "511"
 85) "databases"
 86) "16"
 87) "repl-ping-slave-period"
 88) "10"
 89) "repl-ping-replica-period"
 90) "10"
 91) "repl-timeout"
 92) "60"
 93) "repl-backlog-size"
 94) "1048576"
 95) "repl-backlog-ttl"
 96) "3600"
 97) "maxclients"
 98) "10000"
 99) "watchdog-period"
100) "0"
101) "slave-priority"
102) "100"
103) "replica-priority"
104) "100"
105) "slave-announce-port"
106) "0"
107) "replica-announce-port"
108) "0"
109) "min-slaves-to-write"
110) "0"
111) "min-replicas-to-write"
112) "0"
113) "min-slaves-max-lag"
114) "10"
115) "min-replicas-max-lag"
116) "10"
117) "hz"
118) "10"
119) "cluster-node-timeout"
120) "15000"
121) "cluster-migration-barrier"
122) "1"
123) "cluster-slave-validity-factor"
124) "10"
125) "cluster-replica-validity-factor"
126) "10"
127) "repl-diskless-sync-delay"
128) "5"
129) "tcp-keepalive"
130) "300"
131) "cluster-require-full-coverage"
132) "yes"
133) "cluster-slave-no-failover"
134) "no"
135) "cluster-replica-no-failover"
136) "no"
137) "no-appendfsync-on-rewrite"
138) "no"
139) "slave-serve-stale-data"
140) "yes"
141) "replica-serve-stale-data"
142) "yes"
143) "slave-read-only"
144) "yes"
145) "replica-read-only"
146) "yes"
147) "slave-ignore-maxmemory"
148) "yes"
149) "replica-ignore-maxmemory"
150) "yes"
151) "stop-writes-on-bgsave-error"
152) "yes"
157) "rdbchecksum"
158) "yes"
159) "activerehashing"
160) "yes"
161) "activedefrag"
162) "no"
163) "protected-mode"
164) "no"
165) "repl-disable-tcp-nodelay"
166) "no"
167) "repl-diskless-sync"
168) "no"
169) "aof-rewrite-incremental-fsync"
170) "yes"
171) "rdb-save-incremental-fsync"
172) "yes"
173) "aof-load-truncated"
174) "yes"
175) "aof-use-rdb-preamble"
176) "yes"
177) "lazyfree-lazy-eviction"
178) "no"
179) "lazyfree-lazy-expire"
180) "no"
181) "lazyfree-lazy-server-del"
182) "no"
183) "slave-lazy-flush"
184) "no"
185) "replica-lazy-flush"
186) "no"
187) "dynamic-hz"
188) "yes"
189) "maxmemory-policy"
190) "noeviction"
191) "loglevel"
192) "notice"
193) "supervised"
194) "no"
195) "appendfsync"
196) "everysec"
197) "syslog-facility"
198) "local0"
199) "appendonly"
200) "yes"
201) "dir"
202) "/data"
203) "save"
204) ""
205) "client-output-buffer-limit"
206) "normal 0 0 0 slave 268435456 67108864 60 pubsub 33554432 8388608 60"
207) "unixsocketperm"
208) "0"
209) "slaveof"
210) ""
211) "notify-keyspace-events"
212) ""
213) "bind"
214) ""
```

And here is the logs before redis stopped listening to the requests [redis logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjzAv.png)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found that this commands where exectued by another client to provoke the DB saved disk and also the command SlaveOf to turn the master node into slave.

The configuration of redis is good.